# When does the weekly drop count reset?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Ever since the weekly drop limits went into place, I only get a few items a week.  What is the exact time each week the drop count resets?

Comment: Good question, I am interested too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the [official TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system#Current_Item_Drop_System):

> The system resets each player's playtime cap every **Thursday at approximately 00:00 Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)**.

This is approximate - there may not be a single, precise time for everyone. Not everything published in the official tf2 wiki is in itself official, though.

Comment: very good link

Answer (score 0):

It should be midnight (between Wednesday and Thursday) UK time. Again, this is approximate, as I've started getting drops again as early as 9/10pm on Wednesday night, having used up the 10/11 hours playtime per week allowed for item drops.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one cap, and yes it is on Thursday at 00:00 UTC. Sometimes I get three items a day so there is definitively not a daily cap.