# What is the limit on finding items in TF2? How can I tell if I have hit this?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I believe I read that after X hours of playing Team Fortress 2 in a period of Y days, you stop finding items. How long do I have before I stop finding items? And if I hit this limit of gameplay, how do I tell?

Comment: Similar: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322/when-is-the-weekly-drop-count-reset-in-team-fortress-2

Comment: @Drake Has that changed in the past year, though?

Comment: If I remember well Valve hasn't published any official change to the items drop cap system in the last year, but I am not sure. Of course they could have changed details in the algorithm without telling around.

Comment: This is bound to Valve Policy and is constantly changed, making a definitive answer impossible.

Comment: @Bora: Other than during double-drop rate weeks, it hasn't changed in well over a year.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [official Team Fortress 2 Wiki page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system):

> The current item drop system was introduced on April 20, 2010. Players are guaranteed to find items at **regular intervals of 30 to 70 minutes**, with an average interval of 50 minutes. [...] There is no cap on the amount of items that can be received per week, but instead **a cap on the amount of playtime in which drops can occur**. This cap has been **estimated to 10 hours each week** ([resetting] every Thursday). **Playing beyond the cap won't yield additional items**. Playing less than the cap carries over unused time to the next week, increasing that week's cap to a maximum of two weeks' worth of playtime. [...] Receiving a Mann Co. Supply Crate or **any usable item does not count against the cap**...

And to answer your question of *"and if I hit this limit of gameplay, how do I tell?"*, I guess you could time yourself playing for 70 minutes, and if you don't receive any items, you've hit the cap.

Comment: adn how about this: yesterday was thursday and there has still been no item drop while i have been playing all day

Comment: does it include time spent at the home screen/not playing?

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, yes there is a limit of normal items (weapons and such) but it capped with time. as stated above, 10 hours weekly, with the timer resetting at 00:00 Greenwich time (7pm EST),  Crates and items like that though are own its own system, and will still drop after the 10 hour mark.